# jQueryUI for dialog not working

Tags: jquery

I tried to using jQuery to create a simple dislog box but it did not work. I think it conflict with my other Wowslider jQuery banner, but i tried many way, it did not still work.
**I tried to put (jQuery) at the end, and i tried to use document.ready**

**Here is the dialog box i get from jqueryui.com:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
    $(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can      be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery from wowslider that locate on the bottom of index page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: my bet is you have included jQuery library more than once in page or this is a CMS like wordpress that uses `noConflict`. WHat errors are thrown in console?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, and below are the errors of the chrome broswers. thanks

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
script.js:91 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
www-embed-player.js:169 GET chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
www-embed-player.js:169 GET chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
www-embed-player.js:169 GET chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: www-embed-player.js:169 GET chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
www-embed-player.js:169 GET chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
www-embed-player.js:169 GET chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
www-embed-player.js:169 GET chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED